# Kth Smallest Element in BST

Tags: data-structures, binary-search-tree, depth-first-search

Doing this problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/kth-smallest-element-in-a-bst/

Solution:

```
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<>();      
    while(root != null || !stack.isEmpty()) {          
        while(root != null) {              
            stack.push(root);                  
            root = root.left;             
        }           
        root = stack.pop();          
        if(--k == 0) break;          
        root = root.right;      
    }      
    return root.val;  }

Example Walkthrough: https://repl.it/@Stylebender/Kth-Smallest-BST

Just wondering why the answer I get from my walkthrough (5) doesn't seem to be correct answer(4).
```

Comment: You are asking a question about a test case you haven;t posted.

Comment: Hi Sorry, there's a repl link in my initial post? Ive put it there due to the length of the walkthrough...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the code you pasted here is doing pre-decrement and the code in your workspace is doing post-decrement.

**If you want the result in 0-based index you need to use pre-decrement and opposite for 1-based index.**

Comment: Thank you! Even if I did switch it to pre-decrement how do I get final answer of root = 4? Sorry still a newbie...

Comment: If you use pre decrement of K, first its value will be decrement then it will go for equality checking. the inorder traversal of the tree will gives you 1 2 3 4 .. and so on. now K's value will be decrement like 3 (node value- 1),  2 (node value-2), 1 (node value-3), 0 (node value -4, this is the answer)

Comment: I've applied your logic: https://repl.it/@Stylebender/Kth-Smallest-BST#Main.java

Still getting 5 though? Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: make sure you are popping up node first from stack, then assign popped node's right child to root. for example

    root  = stack.pop();
    
    if(--k == 0) {
     return root.val;
    }
                             root = root.child;